# html form input javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am doing a HTML form input where by user are able to add-on the input field.

the HTML code are as followed

```
<form name="calculate" onSubmit="return submitForm(this.form)">
<fieldset>
            <legend> calculate time  </legend>
            perform by: <input type="text" name="perform" id="perform" value=""/><br/><br/>
            <div id="newlink">
            <div>
            <table border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td> Date: </td>
                    <td> Start Time: </td>
                    <td> Stop Time: </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="date" name="Pdate[]" id="Pdate[]" value=""/></td>
                    <td> <input type="time" name="Stime[]" id="Stime[]" value=""/></td>
                    <td><input type="time" name="Etime[]" id="Etime[]" value=""/></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
            <br/>
            </div>
            </div>

            <p id="addnew">
                <a href="javascript:new_link()"><input type="button" name="Add New" value="Add New"/></a>
            </p>

            <!-- Template for add on after 'Add new' button is click -->
            <div id="addnewfield" style="display:none">
            <div>
            <table border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="date" name="Pdate[]" id="Pdate[]" value=""/></td>
                        <td> <input type="time" name="Stime[]" id="Stime[]" value=""/></td>
                        <td><input type="time" name="Etime[]" id="Etime[]" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried to call the form to get the array value but the value doesn't seem to parse in

script code are as followed (all script and html code are in a single .html file

```
var pdate, startTime, endTime, totalTime;

<script>
function submitForm(frm){

    var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var a, s = 0;

    for (a =0; a < e.length; a++){
        if (e[i].type== "time" && e[i].name== "Stime[]"){
            s++;
        }
        alert (s);
    }

/*
    startTime = document.getElementById['Stime[]'];
    endTime = frm.elements['Etime[]'];


    alert(startTime[0].value);


    if (! startTime.length) {
        alert (startTime.value + "<br/>" + endTime.value);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i<startTime.length; i++){
        alert ( startTime[i].value + "<br/>" + endTime[i].value);
    }
    return true;*/

}
```

with all this, there were still no alert message pop up.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: change `<input type="button" name="Add New" value="Add New"/>` to `<input type="submit" name="Add New" value="Add New"/>`; input[type=button] will not submit the form automatically. check this [input type=submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit)

Comment: Well it is simple `i !== a`. The typo in the for loop is creating an error that would show up in your console if you set your console up to not clear itself on page navigation.

Comment: @Sphinx yes, my button type is submit

Comment: @epascarello do you mean for (a =0; i !== a; a++) if so is still doesnt work.

Comment: `e[i].type` <-- you use `i` here and you have `var a` in your for loop...

Comment: @epascarello oh ya, thanks for highlighting.
BTW, do you have any idea how to get the value from the array of the input form?
var stor = e[a].value;